# Discrete mathematics and the big O problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let f(n) = n + 100 and g(n) = n^2, show that f(n) does not dominate g(n). My work so far is this and the parts that I will bold print is the work of textbook that I don't understand:

Let  n > max {100+m, k} , then n^2 > (100 +m)n = **100n + mn > 100m +mn** = m(100+n) = m|f(n)|

Can someone explain to me how the book changed **100n to 100m**?? Very confused here and would appreciate some explanation on this weird change of variable. In previously similar questions, I've never had to suddenly change a variable, but how come now it's all of a sudden changing 100n to 100m? What was the logic behind this? Whens should I be doing this?

Comment: I don't get this either. All we need to show is there are some $m$ and $K$ such that $K|g(n)| \geq |f(n)|$ for $m \geq n$. I.e. for sufficiently large $n$, $g$ grows at least as fast as $f$, possibly within a constant factor $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n > \max\{100+m,k\} \implies n > m$

Comment: how come we don't change mn to mm then as well ?

Comment: It makes sense, but I did about 4 previous questions like this, but different numbers and none of them ever had to change the variable.

Comment: @user3718584 You could if you wanted to (and the resulting inequality would be true), but that doesn't give you something you want, namely, the $100+n$ to pop out. Constructing proofs is not always a "linear" or "formulaic" process, so some steps/techniques will seem like pulling something from thin air.

Comment: I figured it was to make 100 + n to pop up, but what made me question this was whether or not there was a deeper meaning for this variable change? Maybe I am overthinking it...

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here.  One is mathematical:  how do you justify the argument?  You already have stated that $n \gt 100+m \gt m$, so $n \gt m$  Then $100n \gt 100m$ and the argument goes through.  The second is more creative:  how do you think of this?  That is harder, it helps to write the proof from both ends and see what it takes to meet in the middle.  You discover that the approximations you need are like this.